# Swift using high order functions

Tags: swift, dictionary

I wanna collect all cities with towns in a dictionary like [String: [String]]. But because of models, I cannot append townNames to dictionary. My models like below. Because of the [TownModel], I cannot get townName as string. It works with [String: [TownModel]] dictionary. But I want to use my [String: [String]] dictionary. What should I add to my code ?

```
open class CityListResponseModel: BaseResponseProtocol {
    public var cityCode: Int?
    public var cityName: String?
    public var towns: [TownModel]?
}

open class TownModel: Codable {
    public var townCode: Int?
    public var townName: String?
}

//My code
var dictionary: [String: [String]]
let dict = list.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.cityName, default: []].append($1.towns) }
```

Comment: `append($1.towns)` => `append($1.towns.compactMap{ $0.townName})`?

Comment: correct thanks, how can i get all cityNames ?

Comment: `list.compactMap{ $0.cityName }` or `Array(dict.values)`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use like:

```
        var dictionary: [String: [String]] = [:]
        let list: [CityListResponseModel] = []
        list.forEach { (city) in
            dictionary[city.cityName ?? ""] = city.towns?.map({$0.townName ?? ""})
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, improve your model. There is no reason to have an optional array, or a non-final class.

(There may also be no reason for `cityCode` or `cityName` to be optional either. The "city" prefix also seems redundant, as does the "town" one. Check on all that.)

```swift
final class CityListResponseModel: BaseResponseProtocol {
  public var cityCode: Int?
  public var cityName: String?
  public var towns: [TownModel]
}
```

With that,

```swift
Dictionary(
  list.compactMap { city in
    city.cityName.map { ($0, city.towns.compactMap(\.townName)) }
  },
  uniquingKeysWith: +
)
```